# How to add a dotted line on top of existing chart in Apache Echarts

Tags: charts, bar-chart, visualization, echarts, apache-echarts

I was tasked to implement a chart made by our design team,i took a look at the echarts [cheatsheet](https://echarts.apache.org/en/cheat-sheet.html) and i couldnt find what i needed, i'm trying to implement this dotted line that represents the median value :

[image]

so far i arrived at this :

[image]

what is that vertical dotted called in Echarts ? can i extract the median value automatically based on my dataset source ?

Also how to add a label "Moyenne" which refers to that dotted line ?

This is my current options object :

```
const barColors: string[] = ["#5BA0B4", "#E6BE72", "#4C2E25", "#809D92", "#CCA0B9", "#75273B", "#E7728E", "#C6DDE4", "#9A7F4D", "#53645D", "#D1836E", "#79566A", "#D1DCD8", "#295765", "#E04F71", "#F3D5A1", "#A0604E"];
      const optionsBarCharthorizontal: EChartsOption = {
        legend: {},
        tooltip: {},
        dataset: {
          source: [
            ...(parseScenarios(data) || []),
          ]
        },
        xAxis: { type: 'value' },
        yAxis: {
          type: 'category',
          inverse: true,
        },
        series: [
          {
            type: 'bar',
            realtimeSort: true,
            itemStyle: {
              color: function (params) {
                return barColors[params.dataIndex];
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

Any help appreciated ! i'm new to data visualization in general and never used Echarts before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echart has feature to show line(markLine): [EXAMPLE](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?code=MYewdgzgLgBARgQwE4GEQBsRIjAvDAbQCgYYByAYgFYAhAQQAYaAWMgGhPIoFEA2G7gHYATO06VmKYd2FUxpSgA4GATgAiK0RwUUUKRjRXyugqsMEBmGscpCRi7jd281a7q21cVdQQDFmak5UFrzMVIGelGoAjIohjpEUgipUvLx0TjFqKGqKTsIpgrxyidwMzL6C0U6-FmpUdNWJjLzljkQAugDcRCAADlAAluB4MADenOgApgDmU2AAJgBc4wC-nlAgGEN9K2PrnACedAAegxB7nKQLCFAIKwRkALLg7OQAKgCuU29kAOpTBa_d4AC0-v18SEGvwAyrdYZ8wGQOp5SIMwAA3KbYKYrKBIb6cA6kE6nc57YkwCDYwZTC6EK7jRmkKCHPq48iIJDGUikJBTBDoIYAWymMKwUDxBKmqN5NzuDyobBgwgYypCyuiSpV2tVyuYKOZMEGUCmwphrOml15NpgoEwSBWADNEcAhiMABR9ZAIYUQACUTNttv5UE-SDA8GQaAdEAI3qQvogADp5QgAJKLKYnbpG0irI2Um3C5AAawAMuiORNg6R0Ag4FN0Nba6QICCQAB3Z2C6l5mBF21ph790g11u81nslZkUULQYIJGjgf9w2tiCDaZgSUwfGE4MFm2HmAdIirLpAA&_source=echarts-doc-preview)

Also, Echart supports `'min', 'max', 'average', 'median'` as a data type. for more info: [click here](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.markLine.data)